# Vertical stacked div layout with a responsive SVG

Tags: html, css, layout

Okay, so I suck at div layouts (I mostly work with interactive SVG elements and D3).

Here's my issue. I am trying to stack two divs within a parent container with an absolute height (say 600px).

The first div is an inline responsive SVG, the height of which can scale from ~190 to ~380px depending on screen width.
The second div contains a table, which is populated based on mouseclicks within the svg element (overflow scrolling enabled).

What I am trying to do is set the height of the second div to fill (but not exceed) the remaining space in the parent div depending on the height of the svg div container (and it must work on mobile devices).

I tried a couple of different layouts (including a table) but none of them seemed to fit the bill.

i.e.:
[Desired layout of containers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUw6X.jpg)

Layout code follows:

```
<div id='parent'>
<div class="imgsvg3">
<svg  class="my-svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" id="svg" height="100%" width="100%" viewBox="0 0 300.02 189.75" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">

</svg>
</div>
<div id="table-wrapper">
  <div id="table-scroll">
    <table id='table' border="1">
<thead><tr>
<th title="Field #1"><span>Name</span></th>
<th title="Field #2"><span>Department</span></th>
<th title="Field #3">Destination</th>
<th title="Field #4">State</th>
<th title="Field #5">Dates of travel</th>
<th title="Field #6">Estimated cost</th>
<th title="Field #7">Reason</th>
</tr></thead>
<tbody>
</tbody></table>

    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#parent {
height:600px;
}
#table-wrapper {
 border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
  position:relative;
}
#table-scroll {
  height:200px;
  overflow:auto;  
  margin-top:20px;
}

.my-svg{
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.imgsvg3{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 60%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple solution with jQuery. It sets the below div height to whatever is remaining of the container.

**See fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/LsppgzLt/

**Another fiddle with** `padding-bottom`: http://jsfiddle.net/28dy4864/

You could then call the `refresh()` function whenever you like to, e.g. with a listener on the SVG element, if needed. An example:

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="svg-holder"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    border: 2px solid #333;
}
.svg-holder {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background: #666;
}
.box {
    width: 100%;
    background: #999;
}
```

JS:

```
var refresh = function(){
    $(".box").height( $(".container").height() - $(".svg-holder").height());
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    refresh();
});
```

Comment: The problem is, to enforce responsiveness in IE I'm using:   padding-bottom: 60%; on the div containing the svg element.
That would seem to break the layout.

Comment: I *think* I have it working. Will test in all the browsers. Thanks for your response!

Comment: @NickMalawskey I would say that you can have the `padding-bottom` for the element inside the holder, that is the common way of doing it. It's a nice trick to get a fixed aspect ratio but remaining responsive.

Comment: @NickMalawskey I also added another fiddle to demonstrate that. But great that you got it working!

Answer (score 0):

Please don't use script when something can be done wíth css (unless you for some reason can't or are not allowed).

There is no reason to put more workload on a device, specially phones/tablets which has less power than a computer (though that gap is decreasing), than necessaray, it will just slow down your app and the users overall experience will be less good.

Here is a simple sample using css only (support down to IE8).

Note: I set the total height to 400px so you can see how it works.

```css
html,
body { margin: 0 }

.container {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
}
.page-row {
    display: table-row;
    height: 0;
}
.page-row-expanded {
    height: 100%;
}

main .content {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: #eee;
}

.header {
    background-color: #bbb;
    padding: 10px;
    min-height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

    <header class="page-row">
        <div class="header">
            <a href=''>Header, dynamically grow, now set to min-height: 150px;</a><br />              
        </div>
    </header>

    <main class="page-row page-row-expanded">
        <div class="content">
          <table id='table' border="1">
            <thead><tr>
              <th title="Field #1"><span>Name</span></th>
              <th title="Field #2"><span>Department</span></th>
              <th title="Field #3">Destination</th>
              <th title="Field #4">State</th>
              <th title="Field #5">Dates of travel</th>
              <th title="Field #6">Estimated cost</th>
              <th title="Field #7">Reason</th>
              </tr></thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody></table>

            <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
            Content container, that stretch when to little text and scroll when it is full<br />
            <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
            <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
            <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
        </div>
    </main>
    
</div>
```